# Resize all elements inside a container using jQuery

Tags: jquery

So I have a container (DIV) which would be resized using the correct aspect ratio (so it doesn't stretch) when user resize the window.

Now I would like to dynamically resize all the elements inside that container using jQuery, keeping in mind that they also should keep their aspect ration correctly.

I know there is a CSS3 2D Transforms option but I would like to do that without using CSS3 and only jQuery and old CSS so it also works in older version of IE.

Here is the code, as you can see the image will maintain its aspect ratio since I used the width=100% but other elements have their own size (width and height) which cannot be in percent.

So ideally I like to set the width, height, top and left position of those elements when resizing the window keeping their aspect ration correctly.
http://jsfiddle.net/Km8Ef/1/

Any good solutions?

Comment: Why not to use CSS width and height? E.g. width: 25%;

Comment: So is that hard to do without CSS3 I guess?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know exactly what you are trying to accomplish without seeing some markup, but why not just use percentage widths? the container would be manually set based on your code...

```
<div id="container" style="width:500px">
    <div id="inner" style="width:50%">
        <img style="width:100%" src="image.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```